# Use the second value in a list to carry out operation during initial run of a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I call a certain value from a dictionary based on the values on a `list_a`?

```
list_a = ['S', 'D', 'E']

dict_list = {'S': [('A', 8), ('B', 4), ('D', 6)], 'D': [('C', 5,), ('E', 3)], }

for i in list_a:
    print(i)
```

for I would like to add the value from 'S' to 'D' and then add the value from 'D' to 'E'.

For this example, the answer I am looking for is 9. Basically S to D = 6 and D to E = 3.

Comment: Please add your expected output, it would be super helpful.

Comment: 9. basically S to D = 6 and D to E = 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use

```
list_a = ['S', 'D', 'E']
dict_list = {'S': [('A', 8), ('B', 4), ('D', 6)], 'D': [('C', 5), ('E', 3)]}

sum(dict(dict_list[x])[y] for x, y in zip(list_a, list_a[1:]))
# 9
```

What this does is get pairs of indices, extract the value from the corresponding entries, then sums up the total.

If it is possible for keys not to exist, you may use change `dict(dict_list[x])[y]` to `dict(dict_list.get(x, {}).get(y, 0)`.